# Unable to load fragments from the navigation drawer menu item

Tags: java, android

Hi i am a student & trying to build a app. where i want to load fragment via tapping on the navigation drawer into the main activity. i am able to attach navigation drawer to home activity. but using following code i am unable to load fragment in the activity. "loadDashboard" function is working fine, but "onNavigationItemSelected" method is not working. please help...code are bellow...

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    loadDashboad();

    NavigationView nv = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menuitemdashboard:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewContainer, new dashboard()).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.menuitemlogout:
                    break;
                case R.id.menuitemprofile:
                    break;
                case R.id.menuitemreports:
                    break;
                case R.id.menuitemvisits:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewContainer, new visits()).commit();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}

private void loadDashboad() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    dashboard dash = new dashboard();
    ft.add(R.id.viewContainer, dash);
    ft.commit();
}
```

}

Comment: Please someone help me!

Comment: did you try to debug?

Comment: Do all your Fragments extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, what you are missing is to give the navigation menu items a function to do. Replace the following lines with the fragments that you want to add

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menuitemdashboard:
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewContainer, new dashboard()).commit();
        break;
    case R.id.menuitemlogout:
        //TODO replace logout with fragment
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewContainer, //*log out*/).commit();
        break;
    case R.id.menuitemprofile:
        //TODO replace profile with fragment
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewContainer, //*profile*/).commit();
        break;
    case R.id.menuitemreports:
        //TODO replace reports with fragment
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewContainer, //*reports*/).commit();
        break;
    case R.id.menuitemvisits:
        fmbeginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewContainer, new visits()).commit();
        break;
}
```